# OpenCV iOS blocks Crash

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, crash, block

I'm doing the processing of the Mat image on my own serial queue. This results in a crash. How do I retain the Mat image before the Q and release it in the Q after the processing is done?

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
{
  // Do some OpenCV stuff with the image
  dispatch_async(imageProcessingQ, ^{
        [self.imageController processImage:image];
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide crash log?

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing the C++ reference `image`, and then using it at in the block which is run asynchronously at a later time. The reference is probably no longer valid at that time.

Comment: Yup, you are right. I want to  retain the object and release the object like this. How do I do this with OpenCV(C++ objects)?

    - (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
    {
      
      //[image retain]
      dispatch_async(imageProcessingQ, ^{
            [self.imageController processImage:image];
            //[image releae];
      });
    }

Comment: @LessaAntony: maybe you can just pass `Mat` into the method instead, not `Mat&`

Comment: processImage() is the callback function what OpenCV has provided.It gives us a reference. Do you want me to clone it and provide it my method? but cloning is expensive as it copies data.

Comment: @LessaAntony: okay, if the parameter must be `Mat &`, then assign it to a local `Mat` inside the function outside of the block, and then use that inside the block.